# Problem with redux middleware - Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a small issue that I can't figure out. I'm making an app that uses Redux. And I want to make one action creator whose dispatches another actions. I've included redux-thunk middleware but still I'm getting the same error.

I was trying to directly pass objects in those dispatches instead of methods that returns those objects but still the same error occurs. Also I've been trying to apply redux-thunk in different ways but still the same error.

**This is this big action creator:**

```
  import {fetchMoviesBegin, fetchMoviesSuccess, fetchMoviesFailure} from 
  '../movie-results/movie-results.action';

  const API_KEY = "d14e23d0";

   export const getResults = async (inputValue) => {
   return dispatch => {
   dispatch(fetchMoviesBegin());
   return (async () => {
     try {
       const getAPIS = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?a 
       pikey=${API_KEY}&s=${inputValue}`);
       const apiTOJSON = await getAPIS.json();

    //Array ID's assignment
    const returnedValues = apiTOJSON.Search;
    const getIDS = returnedValues.map(item => item.imdbID);

    //Array full of fetched items info
    const fetchInfo = await Promise.all(getIDS.map(id => 
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&i=${id}`).then(item 
    => item.json())));

    //Here is the sorted array full of movies with details 
    fetchInfo.sort((a, b) => (a.imdbRating > b.imdbRating) ? -1 : 1);
    dispatch(fetchMoviesSuccess(fetchInfo));
    return fetchInfo;
  }catch(error) {
    return () => dispatch(fetchMoviesFailure(error));
          }
        })()
      }
    }
```

**Here are those actions:**

```
    import {MovieResultsTypes} from './movie-results.types';

    export const setMovieResults = results => ({
        type: MovieResultsTypes.FETCH_MOVIE_TITLES,
        payload: results
    })

    export const fetchMoviesBegin = () => ({
        type: MovieResultsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_BEGIN
    })

    export const fetchMoviesSuccess = movies => ({
        type: MovieResultsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_SUCCES, 
        payload: {movies}
    })

    export const fetchMoviesFailure = error => ({
        type: MovieResultsTypes.FETCH_MOVIES_FAILURE, 
        payload: {error}
    })
```

**And here is the store with middlewares:**

```
   import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
   import logger from 'redux-logger';
   import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

   import rootReducer from './root-reducer';

   const middlewares = [logger, thunk];

   export const store = createStore(rootReducer,                      
   applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```

If anyone experienced this problem please help :/

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to dispatch `getResults`? Can you show the code where you do that?

Comment: You should also use a curried function style, looks a bit messy
export const getResults = (inputValue) => async(dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fetchMoviesBegin());
    try { ...

Comment: Yes, I'm dispatching ***getResults*** in ***Header.component*** - and here is the code:   
//Method that send dispatch method and mapDispatchToProps: 

      const handleSubmit = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const {setMovieResults} = this.props;
      setMovieResults(this.state.inputValue);
    };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     setMovieResults: value => dispatch(getResults(value))
     })

     export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this syntax?

Also why do you need to return fetchInfo?  When the store changes, components which are connected to the store will get the new data automatically.

```
  export function getResults(inputValue) {
    ​
      return async (dispatch) => {

        dispatch(fetchMoviesBegin());

        try {
            dispatch(fetchMoviesBegin());

            const getAPIS = await fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&s=${inputValue}`);
            const apiTOJSON = await getAPIS.json();

            //Array ID's assignment
            const returnedValues = apiTOJSON.Search;
            const getIDS = returnedValues.map(item => item.imdbID);

            //Array full of fetched items info
            const fetchInfo = await Promise.all(getIDS.map(id => fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${API_KEY}&i=${id}`)
                .then(item => item.json())));

            //Here is the sorted array full of movies with details 
            fetchInfo.sort((a, b) => (a.imdbRating > b.imdbRating) ? -1 : 1);
            dispatch(fetchMoviesSuccess(fetchInfo));

           // return fetchInfo;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log('error: ', error);
            dispatch(fetchMoviesFailure(error));
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes now it works just fine! Thank You so much, now I see where the problem was and right - I didn't needed to return ***fetchInfo***. Thanks!